# Fork() with FIFO

Tags: c, pipe, fork, gnu, named-pipes

I am having the toughest time with this assignment. So this assignment I have two children(two separate programs) and they have to write to the parent (main). The parent has to read both data from the kids and then print it out. I have to use named pipes. Well so my FIFO keeps giving me "USAGE: NAMEPIPECLIENT[String]" message and I don't know why. The message is on the client side by the way. Also if someone can point me in a good direction on how to use fork with multiply children on separate files that would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance!Using GNU C

My Reader

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<linux/stat.h>
#define FIFO_FILE "MYFIFO"         //default is current directory
int main(void){
  FILE *fpoint;
  char readbuffer[80];
  int again = 1;
  mknod(FIFO_FILE, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
  while(again){
    fpoint = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "r");
    fgets(readbuffer, 80, fpoint);
    printf("recevived string: %s\n, readbuffer");
    fclose(fpoint);
    if(strcmp(readbuffer, "stop") == 0 ) again = 0;
    return(0);
  }//exit main
}
```

My Writer

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<linux/stat.h>
#define FIFO_FILE "MYFIFO"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  FILE *fpoint;
  int again =1;
  char strIn[80] = "Use message from command line";
  if(argc !=2){
    printf("USAGE: NamedPipeClient[string]\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  strcpy(strIn, argv[1]);
  while(again == 1){
    if((fpoint = fopen (FIFO_FILE, "w")) == NULL){
      perror("fopen");
      exit(1);
    }
    fputs(strIn, fpoint);
    fclose(fpoint);
    printf("Enter message to send: ");
    scanf("%s", strIn);
    again = strcmp(strIn, "Stop");
  }

  if((fpoint = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "w")) == NULL){
    perror("fopen");
    exit(1);
  }

  fputs(strIn,fpoint);
  fclose(fpoint);
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Your title says "fork" but your code doesn't call fork anywhere??

Comment: @JohnZwinck I have the fork, but that's not relevant. When I say fork I mean a child and parent process.

Comment: I'm just trying to get the FIFO implemented first, so I can input the fork later

Comment: Show us the invocation of the writer.  It's printing the usage because you're invoking it wrong.

Comment: Thats all I have in the writer :( and I don't know what you mean by invocation @JohnZwinck

Comment: How is the writer program started?  By what?

Comment: I do a "gcc -o reader reader.c" and then I execute "./reader" Then the cursor will blink, So I open up a new terminal do the same thing for my writer and the message pops up. @JohnZwinck

Comment: So you're launching `./writer` without any arguments?  But it requires a string argument on the command line when you run it!

Comment: Then why am I only able to send one string? @JohnZwinck

Comment: I'll do ./writer with a random string and then the reader will take it and close

Comment: Nevermind, I just got it lol @JohnZwinck but I do have another question, think I should make a new post or ask right now.. Its more about forks

Comment: Why don't  you just delete this train wreck and start a new question?  :)

Comment: lol thats fine. I'll be looking for your answer!! @JohnZwinck

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  2) when indenting, use more than 2 spaces because 2 spaces tends to not be visible when using variable width fonts. Suggest using 4 spaces

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%s", strIn);`  1) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s` format conversion specifier, always use a `max length` modifier so the user cannot overrun the input buffer.  because overrunning the input buffer results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: do not `#include <linux/stat.h>`   nor `#include <sys/stat.h> Nothing in those header files are being used

Comment: in the pair of lines: `while(again == 1)` and `again = strcmp(strIn, "Stop");`  the returned value from `strcmp()` could be `-1`  then the loop would exit before a 'Stop` string was encountered.  Suggest: `while(again)`  AND what if the user entered "stop" or "STOP"   those strings would not match, so the code would stay in the loop, when it was supposed to exit.

Comment: this line: `scanf("%s", strIn);` should be: `scanf("%79s", strIn);`  to avoid buffer overflows

Comment: the writer process is looking for `Stop` but the reader process is looking for `stop`    Capitalization counts!   The reader will never match what the writer is sending for a termination string.

Comment: before calling `mknode()` should call `unlink()` on the same file.  Always check the returned value from `mknode()` to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extensively corrected version of the writer process

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
//#include<sys/stat.h>
//#include<linux/stat.h>

#define FIFO_FILE "MYFIFO"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc !=2)
    {
        printf("USAGE: NamedPipeClient[string]\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fpoint;
    if((fpoint = fopen (FIFO_FILE, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }

    char strIn[80];
    strcpy(strIn, argv[1]);


    int again =1;
    while(again == 1)
    {
        fputs(strIn, fpoint);

        printf("Enter message to send: ");
        scanf("%79s", strIn);
        again = strcmp(strIn, "Stop");
    }

    fputs(strIn,fpoint);
    fclose(fpoint);
    return(0);
}
```

This is the main reason that only one string is read:

```
while(again)
{
    fpoint = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "r");
    fgets(readbuffer, 80, fpoint);
    printf("recevived string: %s\n, readbuffer");
    fclose(fpoint);
    if(strcmp(readbuffer, "stop") == 0 ) again = 0;
    return(0);
}
```

Note that the function returns after only one pass through the loop.

Suggest:

```
while(again)
{
    fpoint = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "r");
    fgets(readbuffer, 80, fpoint);
    printf("recevived string: %s\n, readbuffer");
    fclose(fpoint);
    if(strcmp(readbuffer, "stop") == 0 ) again = 0;
}

return 0;
```

Note: `return` is not a function, (similar to `sizeof` is not a function), so no parens needed.

Note: the continually opening and closing of the FIFO is not a good idea.

Suggest only open once in any one process.

Suggest only close once in any one process.

When calling `fopen()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.